# CakePHP set::combine(). Need a numeric array transformed into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have been attempting to structure an array using the [set::combine](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1492/combine) method, and I cannot get it working (what am I doing wrong!).

And I will note I need to turn this into an associative array like:

```
[Tree] => Array
         (
             [id] => 1
             [name] => Pine
          )...
```

Here is an example of my Array:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [Tree] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => Pine
                    )

            )

    )...
```

And here is my set::combine call:

```
$combine = Set::combine($this->data,'{n}.Tree.id','{n}.Tree.name');
debug($combine);
```

And here is the debug output of $combine:

```
Array
(
    [] => 
)
```

I can do:

```
$combine = Set::combine($this->data,'{n}.{n}.Tree.id','{n}.{n}.Tree.name');
```

But I still get the numeric index!

```
Array
 (
[Array] => Array
    (
        [0] => Oak nnn
    )

)
```

I've tried every example and have been over the manual section on combine all evening. Can't get this working : (

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what specific format the output array needs to be. If the first dimension of the array is a single row, you should be able to do the following:

```
array_values(Set::combine(reset($this->data), '/Tree/id', '/Tree'));
```

If it has multiple rows, you will need to iterate through this first dimension of the array with `foreach`, and `Set::combine` each row in turn, using `Set::merge` to merge the results into your output array:

```
$outArray = array()
foreach($this->data as $row) {
    $outArray = Set::merge( $outArray, Set::combine($row, '/Tree/id', '/Tree'));
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

#### Update:

Based on the requirements clarified in the comments, you would transform the arrays like this:

```
$outArray = array('Tree'=>array());
foreach($this->data as $row) {
    $outArray['Tree'] = Set::merge(
        $outArray['Tree'],
        Set::combine($row, '{n}.Tree.id', '{n}.Tree')
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the idea. The merge and foreach seem to have assisted greatly, but the main issue I am facing is using a non-numeric index as it is now. I am trying to achieve an associative array format with no numbers like: [Tree] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Fur
                        )

Comment: I don't understand. Can you edit your question with a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) of an exemplar array you're working with?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I apologize for being unclear. Here is a pastebin of the array I am trying to format. Basically the index should not be numeric and only associative. Link: http://pastebin.com/SuSJENR5

Answer (score 0):

I understand what specific format the output array needs to be. If the first dimension of the array is a single row, you should be able to remove like following code

```
$combine = Set::classicExtract($this->data, '{n}.Tree');
```